# How do I check if a string contains at least one character from another string?

Tags: java, regex

I'm using Java 6.  I have a string that contains "special" characters -- "!@#$%^&*()_".  How do I write a Java expression to check if another string, "password", contains at least one of the characters defined in the first string?  I have

```
regForm.getPassword().matches(".*[\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\_\\+].*")
```

but I don't want to hard-code the special characters, rather load them into a string from a properties file.  So I'm having trouble figuring out how to escape everything properly after I load it from the file.

Comment: how about put all letters to one arraylist and second letters of word to another arraylist? Then you will iterate letters from one list and calling if contains(element) in that second list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try creating regex from string that contains special characters  and escape symbols using [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29). Try this:

```
String special = "!@#$%^&*()_";
String pattern = ".*[" + Pattern.quote(special) + "].*";
regFrom.getPassword().matches(pattern);
```

Comment: I got similar, build the pattern then do a `password.replaceAll(pattern,"")` then compare the length. but yours is better. +1

Comment: Because of `Pattern.quote` (characters `\Q` and `\E`) inside square brackets, this solution may not work as you're expecting.

Comment: @Nikita, which java version has this method?

Comment: @AlpeshGediya this method available in java 1.5+

Comment: we may need to escape the `]`? if the speical contained it?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Thanks. was looking at javadoc 1.4 ... :(

Comment: @Kent, it is also escaped using `quote`. I checked and it worked as expected.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov, we can achieve this without using quote method, I have tried its working just fine check my answer below.

Comment: This solution will fail to match if `String specialchars = "!@#$%^&*()_["`

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov: If password is: `str = "abc["` and `specialchars = "!@#$%^&*()_["` it returns false instead of expected true.

Comment: @anubhava, If password is: str = "abc[" and specialchars = "!@#$%^&*()_[" it returns true as expected.  Regex string constructed after using Pattern.quote is ".*[\Q!@#$%^&*()_[\E].*"

Answer (score 2):

I think simple looping the regex to check each character might work better and will work for **all the cases**:

```
String special = "!@#$%^&*()_";
boolean found = false;
for (int i=0; i<special.length(); i++) {
   if (regFrom.getPassword().indexOf(special.charAt(i)) > 0) {
      found = true;
      break;
   }
}
if (found) { // password has one of the allowed characters
   //...
   //...
}
```

Comment: May I know which wheel was reinvented by this answer?

Comment: I mean to say when its easily achievable by regex then in my opinion we do not need to write code, what do you think?

Comment: `easily achievable by regex` is questionable actually. What if you have `String specialchars = "!@#$%^&*()_[";` try it you will see an exception being thrown.

Comment: Your solution approach addresses all adverse situation but just do you mind to check condition by executing code... if (regFrom.getPassword().indexOf(special.charAt(i) > 0)  you are iterating over only special characters to this solution to work you need to interate for password string as well.

Comment: @AlpeshGediya: There is a typo, it should be: `if (regFrom.getPassword().indexOf(special.charAt(i)) > 0)`

Comment: Before your this comment I have updated it :D and removed my comment prior to your reply.... :)

Comment: @AlpeshGediya: I removed my response of your comment too :)

Comment: As a defense to this answer, it is the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `StringTokenizer`, and see if it returns more than 1 substring. It has a constructor that allows specifying the characters to split by.

Anyway, my favourite option would be just iterating the characters and using `String.indexOf`.